# Orchard CMS ContentManager.New<>() Specified Cast Was Invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am in the early stages of developing a new module.

Much of it is laid out in terms of the models etc. Also have the migrations all set up and my database now has the tables for my module.

I am encountering the following error when calling `ContentManager.New<myPart>` and would like some help please.

Error is this:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back
Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. 
at Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentCreateExtensions.New[T]
              (IContentManager manager, String contentType)
```

The chunk of code that fires the exception is this:

```
public static T New<T>(this IContentManager manager, string contentType) where T : class, IContent {
            var contentItem = manager.New(contentType);
            if (contentItem == null)
                return null;

            var part = contentItem.Get<T>();
            if (part == null)
                throw new InvalidCastException();

            return part;
        }
```

Here are the various parts to my module that are related to the operation i am struggling with:

**ContentPart**

```
public class GoogleMapsSettingsPart : ContentPart<GoogleMapsSettingsPartRecord>
{
    public string ApiKey { 
        get { return Record.ApiKey; }
        set { Record.ApiKey = value; }
    }
}
```

**ContentPartRecord**

```
public class GoogleMapsSettingsPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

**Handler**

```
public GoogleMapsSettingsPartHandler(IRepository<GoogleMapsSettingsPartRecord> repository)
        {
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
        }
```

**Migration for this table**

```
// Settings Table
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("GoogleMapsSettingsPartRecord", table => table
       .ContentPartRecord()
       .Column("ApiKey", DbType.String, c => c.WithLength(60))
);
```

**Some of the code from the controller for this model etc**

```
public AdminController(IContentManager contentManager, IShapeFactory shapeFactory, IServiceLocatorService serviceLocatorService, INotifier notifier)
        {
            _contentManager = contentManager;
            _serviceLocatorService = serviceLocatorService;
            _notifier = notifier;
            Shape = shapeFactory;
            T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Display Settings
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ActionResult Settings()
        {
            var settings = _serviceLocatorService.GoogleMapsSettings;
            var editor = CreateSettingsEditor(settings);
            var model = _services.ContentManager.BuildEditor(settings);

            return View((object)model);
        }
```

**Finally - the Services where my call throws this exception**

```
private GoogleMapsSettingsPart _settings;
        public GoogleMapsSettingsPart GoogleMapsSettings
        {
            get {
                if (_settings == null)
                {
                    _settings = _contentManager.Query<GoogleMapsSettingsPart, GoogleMapsSettingsPartRecord>().List().FirstOrDefault();

                    if (_settings == null)
                    {
                        _settings = _contentManager.New<GoogleMapsSettingsPart>("GoogleMapsSettings");
                    }
                }
                return _settings;
            }
        }
```

The actual line where the exception happens is `_settings = _contentManager.New<GoogleMapsSettingsPart>("GoogleMapsSettings");`

I have tried all sorts of stuff in place of "GoogleMapsSettings" though nothing is working.

I'm pretty sure at this point it's something simple, though it's avoiding me..My limited knowledge of Orchard is stumping me

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you create the Content Type? You can do that using ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition on the migration or the admin interface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yep, I tried that too - initially I had `ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("GoogleMapsSettings", builder => builder.Attachable());` and still had the same issue. Do all my classes look ok?

Comment: oh - I also tried it with `ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("GoogleMapsSettings", builder => builder.Build());` too - though not sure if that's correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown because your content type does not have the part you specified to get.

```
 _contentManager.New<GoogleMapsSettingsPart>("GoogleMapsSettings");
```

This method call creates a new content item of type `GoogleMapSettings` and gets the content item as a `GoogleMapsSettingsPart`. However, it seems that `GoogleMapSettings` content type does not have a `GoogleMapsSettingsPart`. That's why the exception gets thrown here.

```
var part = contentItem.Get<T>();
if (part == null)
    throw new InvalidCastException();
```

You must either attach the part dynamically to your content type or do it in a migration (or manually in the admin, but that's not a good idea). Your migration should look like this.

```
this.ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("GoogleMapsSettings",
    alt => alt
        .WithPart("GoogleMapsSettingsPart");
```

Comment: Ah, Excellent. Thanks. I had got it working in a different way, though marked yours as answered as it addresses my initial question (that and i learned more from your answer too :) )

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed it...

My understanding of how Orchard works is still very much in the learning stages.

for this particular operation I didn't want to have a content type in the admin - though not sure why after adding the ContentType it still didn't work...

anyway, adding the lines below to my handler took care of the rest. I believe it's actually creating a temporary type so one isn't needed in the system.

```
public GoogleMapsSettingsPartHandler(IRepository<GoogleMapsSettingsPartRecord> repository)
        {
            Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<GoogleMapsSettingsPart>("GoogleMapsSettings"));
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));

            Filters.Add(new TemplateFilterForRecord<GoogleMapsSettingsPartRecord>("GoogleMapsSettings", "Parts/GoogleMapsSettings"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'v got the same error, but in my case it was everything ok with migration class. 
The reason was unlucky merge, which deleted my driver class of my part.
Just look at this code of Activating method of ContentPartDriverCoordinator class. In my case there was no partInfo for my content part and resulted part became ContentPart, so casting throws an exception

```cs
var partInfos = _drivers.SelectMany(cpp => cpp.GetPartInfo()).ToList();

foreach (var typePartDefinition in contentTypeDefinition.Parts) {
    var partName = typePartDefinition.PartDefinition.Name;
    var partInfo = partInfos.FirstOrDefault(pi => pi.PartName == partName);
    var part = partInfo != null 
        ? partInfo.Factory(typePartDefinition) 
        : new ContentPart { TypePartDefinition = typePartDefinition };
    context.Builder.Weld(part);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This solved an issue for me. I had created a content part and a content type. I was calling ContentManager.New("MyContentType") and wasn't getting back my MyContentPart in the list of Parts and could NOT figure out why. It turns out that you need a Driver for each part, even though I hadn't gotten as far in my development as developing any display/edit logic. It seems that you need a driver to be able to correctly `ContentManager.New()` an item.